# undefined reference to 'funtion_name'

Tags: c, linux, gcc, terminal, gcc-warning

im having trouble understanding how to get the code in my src folder as shown below to run the header file in the include folder.

[image]

Include contains a `functions.h` file, and src contains a `functions.c` file as well as my `main.c`

The main contains a `#include "functions.h"`, and a reference to a function declared in `function.h` and `function.c`

When i'm in the main directory, to compile everything, I run the following:

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -Iinclude src/main.c
```

But I get this back in the terminal:

```
/tmp/ccHmaM4g.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x78): undefined reference to `sum'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am fairly new to linux, please tell me what I'm doing wrong.
Cheers!

Comment: You're not linking the other c file.

Comment: @tkausl how would I link it?

Comment: Which files are in `src` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link `function.c` into your binary:

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -Iinclude src/main.c src/function.c
```